# How to Insert parameters and declare stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a stored procedure to get 2 parameters of usersID and Month.

Right now I have this, but I want to put those to variables like parameters. How can I do it?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_TaskObjDashboard]
AS
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @UserID INT = 20 
    DECLARE @Dateinput DATETIME

    SELECT 
        COALESCE(@UserID, users.UserID) AS TC, 
        Objtask.Pace, Objtask.Month, salesobj.SalesObjectiveMonth
    FROM 
        TBL_User AS users
    JOIN 
        TBL_Objectives_Task AS Objtask ON users.UserID = Objtask.Consultant
    LEFT JOIN 
        TBL_SalesObjective AS salesobj ON users.UserID = salesobj.UserID
    WHERE 
        users.IsActive = 1  
        AND MONTH('2019-08-25') = MONTH(Objtask.Month) 
        AND users.UserID = COALESCE(@UserID, users.UserID)
END
```

Comment: [CREATE PROCEDURE (Transact-SQL) - Examples
: Passing Parameters - Creating a procedure with input parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#d-creating-a-procedure-with-input-parameters) If you're ever not sure what the syntax for something is, the documentation should be one of your first port of calls. SQL Server's documentation is very complete, and the has a user community that helps maintain and update it. There are very often examples contained in the article as well, making things easier to understand.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think...your error was....

**1. "Cannot assign a default value to a local variable."**

**2. "Must declare the scalar variable "@UserID"."**

**Sol:-**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_TaskObjDashboard]
AS
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @UserID INT
    SET @UserID=20

    DECLARE @Dateinput DATETIME

    SELECT 
        COALESCE(@UserID, users.UserID) AS TC, 
        Objtask.Pace, Objtask.Month, salesobj.SalesObjectiveMonth
    FROM 
        TBL_User AS users
    JOIN 
        TBL_Objectives_Task AS Objtask ON users.UserID = Objtask.Consultant
    LEFT JOIN 
        TBL_SalesObjective AS salesobj ON users.UserID = salesobj.UserID
    WHERE 
        users.IsActive = 1  
        AND MONTH('2019-08-25') = MONTH(Objtask.Month) 
        AND users.UserID = COALESCE(@UserID, users.UserID)
END
```

For More Info...this type of Error..you can follow this link...

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-139.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your Procedure Definition Should Be

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_TaskObjDashboard]
  @UserID INT, @Dateinput datetime
AS
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_TaskObjDashboard]
  @UserID INT, @Dateinput datetime
AS
...
```

Also, don't forget to remove the DECLARE-statements for the variables that you change into parameters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017